# macOS Catalina and User Permissions

Tags: macos, macos-catalina

I think there is an issue with my macOS Catalina installation. I am running the beta, having updated my machine from the previous version. I noticed I can't copy files as an admin to my root folder (/) but im not sure if this was something that was always the case or not.

I found this after first noticing my time machine time capsule wasn't working and i couldn't access the time capsule server all of a sudden.

Anyone experience the same thing?

Comment: I'm not sure what approach to betas is usually taken here, but at least on Ask Different, we typically don't address tech support questions, and suggest than any issues be reported to Apple for them to sort through.

Comment: How are you trying to copy the files? If you are using the Terminal, try granting Terminal global disk permissions from Privacy Settings.

Comment: https://superuser.com/questions/1457169/macos-catalina-and-user-permissions

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because people should file bug reports on beta problems, not bother the community with known buggy unreleased software.

Answer (score -1):

see here ;)
https://emacs.stackexchange.com/questions/53026/how-to-restore-file-system-access-in-macos-catalina
you will find solution.
Clic on MAC preference / security / Privacy / and check all boxes